# How to validate nested object with the same pattern but no limit dept with Joi

Tags: javascript, validation, recursion, joi

Let say I have a nested object in this pattern below and I want to validate it with `Joi`

```
{
    "AND": [
        { "key": "", "value": "" },
        { "key": "", "value": "" },
        { "OR": [
            { "key": "", "value": "" },
            { "key": "", "value": "" },
            { "AND": [
                    { "key": "", "value": "" },
                    { "key": "", "value": "" },
                    ...
                ]
            },
            ...
        ],
        ...
    ]
}
```

Here is my V.1 which allows only 1 level depth:

```
const obj = Joi.object().keys({
  key: Joi.string(),
  value: Joi.string(),
});
obj.keys({
  AND: Joi.array().items(obj),
  OR: Joi.array().items(obj),
}).nand('AND', 'OR');

const nested = Joi.object()
  .keys({
    AND: Joi.array().items(obj),
    OR: Joi.array().items(obj),
  })
  .nand('AND', 'OR');
```

and here the V.2 which allows just 2 level depth:

```
  const obj = Joi.object().keys({
    key: Joi.string(),
    value: Joi.string(),
    AND: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({ key: Joi.string(), value: Joi.string() })),
    OR: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({ key: Joi.string(), value: Joi.string() })),
  });
  
  const nested = Joi.object()
    .keys({
      AND: Joi.array().items(obj),
      OR: Joi.array().items(obj),
    })
    .nand('AND', 'OR');
```

Can someone please suggest me the right way on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Both of your attempts are a great start but as you've found it's the recursive nature of the pattern that's tricky to deal with.

Thankfully Joi has a solution to this with [`.link()`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.0#linkref):

> Links to another schema node and reuses it for validation, typically for creative recursive schemas...

We can also make use of [`.pattern()`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.0#objectpatternpattern-schema-options) to avoid having to duplicate our rules for `AND` and `OR`.

I've found the following schema works:

```
// attempt to match one of these schemas
Joi.alternatives([
    // an object containing the key AND or OR where it's value matches 
    // this entire schema definition
    Joi.object().pattern(/^(AND|OR)$/, Joi.array().items(Joi.link('#schema'))),
    // an object containing a key/value pair
    Joi.object().keys({
        key: Joi.string(),
        value: Joi.string()
    })
// we identify our schema with an ID so we can reference it in Joi.link()
]).id('schema')
```

With test data:

```
{
    "AND": [
        { "key": "", "value": "" },
        { "key": "", "value": "" },
        {
            "OR": [
                { "key": "", "value": "" },
                { "key": "", "value": "" },
                {
                    "AND": [
                        { "key": "", "value": "" },
                        { "key": "", "value": "" }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can test it out [here](https://joi.dev/tester/).

--

For those using a Joi version < v16 that doesn't support `link()`, you can use [`lazy()`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=15.1.1#lazyfn-options---inherits-from-any) instead.

```
const schema = Joi.alternatives([
    Joi.object().pattern(/^(AND|OR)$/, Joi.array().items(Joi.lazy(() => schema))),
    Joi.object().keys({
        key: Joi.string(),
        value: Joi.string()
    })
]);
```

Comment: I didn't know about https://joi.dev/tester/. Usually, I run the tests through https://npm.runkit.com/joi. Actually, joi.dev looks better, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thank you! I will try and let you know later.

Comment: Unlucky me the Joi version we use is too old (v10) and it doesn't support the `link()` yet

Comment: @ckitisak, not to worry it's still possible. I will update my answer...

Comment: Thanks @Ankh! I will try and let you know :)